# How do connections recycle in a multiprocess pool serving requests from a single requests.Session object in python?

Tags: python-requests, multiprocessing, connection-pooling, keep-alive, tcp-keepalive

Below is the complete code simplified for the question.

`ids_to_check` returns a list of ids. For my testing, I used a list of 13 random strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool, current_process as threadpool_process
import requests

def ids_to_check():
     some_calls()
     return(id_list)

def execute_task(id):
     url = f"https://myserver.com/todos/{ id }"
     json_op = s.get(url,verify=False).json()
     value = json_op['id']
     print(str(value) + '-' + str(threadpool_process()) + str(id(s)))

def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
    while True:
        pool.map(execute_task, ids_to_check())
        print("Let's wait for 10 seconds")
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers.update = {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    main()
```

**Output:**

```
4-<DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 140209222559488)>140209446508360
5-<DummyProcess(Thread-5, started daemon 140209123481344)>140209446508360
7-<DummyProcess(Thread-6, started daemon 140209115088640)>140209446508360
2-<DummyProcess(Thread-11, started daemon 140208527894272)>140209446508360
None-<DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 140209230952192)>140209446508360
10-<DummyProcess(Thread-4, started daemon 140209131874048)>140209446508360
12-<DummyProcess(Thread-7, started daemon 140209106695936)>140209446508360
8-<DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 140209140266752)>140209446508360
6-<DummyProcess(Thread-12, started daemon 140208519501568)>140209446508360
3-<DummyProcess(Thread-13, started daemon 140208511108864)>140209446508360
11-<DummyProcess(Thread-10, started daemon 140208536286976)>140209446508360
9-<DummyProcess(Thread-9, started daemon 140209089910528)>140209446508360
1-<DummyProcess(Thread-8, started daemon 140209098303232)>140209446508360
Let's wait for 10 seconds
None-<DummyProcess(Thread-14, started daemon 140208502716160)>140209446508360
3-<DummyProcess(Thread-20, started daemon 140208108455680)>140209446508360
1-<DummyProcess(Thread-19, started daemon 140208116848384)>140209446508360
7-<DummyProcess(Thread-17, started daemon 140208133633792)>140209446508360
6-<DummyProcess(Thread-6, started daemon 140209115088640)>140209446508360
4-<DummyProcess(Thread-4, started daemon 140209131874048)>140209446508360
9-<DummyProcess(Thread-16, started daemon 140208485930752)>140209446508360
5-<DummyProcess(Thread-15, started daemon 140208494323456)>140209446508360
2-<DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 140209222559488)>140209446508360
8-<DummyProcess(Thread-18, started daemon 140208125241088)>140209446508360
11-<DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 140209230952192)>140209446508360
10-<DummyProcess(Thread-11, started daemon 140208527894272)>140209446508360
12-<DummyProcess(Thread-5, started daemon 140209123481344)>140209446508360
Let's wait for 10 seconds
None-<DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 140209140266752)>140209446508360
2-<DummyProcess(Thread-10, started daemon 140208536286976)>140209446508360
1-<DummyProcess(Thread-12, started daemon 140208519501568)>140209446508360
4-<DummyProcess(Thread-9, started daemon 140209089910528)>140209446508360
5-<DummyProcess(Thread-14, started daemon 140208502716160)>140209446508360
9-<DummyProcess(Thread-6, started daemon 140209115088640)>140209446508360
8-<DummyProcess(Thread-16, started daemon 140208485930752)>140209446508360
7-<DummyProcess(Thread-4, started daemon 140209131874048)>140209446508360
3-<DummyProcess(Thread-20, started daemon 140208108455680)>140209446508360
6-<DummyProcess(Thread-8, started daemon 140209098303232)>140209446508360
12-<DummyProcess(Thread-13, started daemon 140208511108864)>140209446508360
10-<DummyProcess(Thread-7, started daemon 140209106695936)>140209446508360
11-<DummyProcess(Thread-19, started daemon 140208116848384)>140209446508360
Let's wait for 10 seconds
.
.
```

**My observation:**

- multiple connections are created (i.e., connection per process), but session object is same throughtout the execution of the code (as session object id is same)
- connections keep recycling as seen from ss output. I couldn't identify any certain pattern/timeout for the recycling
- connections are not recycling if I reduce the processes to a smaller number. (Example: 5)

I do not understand how/why the connections are being recycled and why they are not if I reduce the process count. I have tried disabling the garbage collector `import gc; gc.disable()` and still connections are recycled.

I would like the created connections to keep alive, until it reaches a maximum number of requests. I think it would work without sessions and using keep-alive connection header.

But I am curious to know what causing these sessions connections to keep recycling when a process pool length is high.

I can reproduce this issue with any server, so it may not be dependent on server.

Comment: hey provide me working codePen code then i'll sort out this issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue for myself by creating session for each process and parallelized requests executions. And at first time I used `multiprocessing.dummy` too, but I faced the same issue as yours and changed it to `concurrent.futures.thread.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Here is my solution.

```py
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

from requests import Session, Response
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def thread_pool_execute(iterables, method, pool_size=30) -> list:
    """Multiprocess requests, returns list of responses."""
    session = Session()
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=pool_size))  # that's it
    session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=pool_size))  # that's it    
    worker = partial(method, session)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(pool_size) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, iterables)
    session.close()
    return list(results)

def simple_request(session, url) -> Response:
    return session.get(url)

response_list = thread_pool_execute(list_of_urls, simple_request)
```

I test sitemaps with 200k urls with it with `pool_size=150` without any problems. It's restricts only by target host configuration.

Comment: Fixed it! Needed "from functools import partial"