# Iterate and make requests over a list of URLs asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, url, python-requests, aiohttp

I made a script the other night that made requests to a website 100000 times with a different URL number (ranging from 0000 - 10000). I was using the requests library, but it was extremely slow. Here's my current script:

```
import requests

for num in range(9999):
    num = '{0:04}'.format(num)
    print(num)
    URL = "www.site.com/" + str(num)
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
    print(r.content)
```

I've heard aiohttp allows for asynchronous requests, but I'm not sure the simplest way to do things given what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas?

Comment: The concurrent threads solution from me with configurable pool size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365783/how-do-connections-recycle-in-a-multiprocess-pool-serving-requests-from-a-single/65466690#65466690 if it's not enough for your case - let me know here.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I'm not entirely sure how to adapt it for my case?

Comment: You could try running a bash script. Multiprocessing is much easier to implement.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: One good article for your case is using `grequests` build on top of `requests` and `gevent`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280387/5973377

Answer (score 0):

> The concurrent threads solution from me with configurable pool size: [How do connections recycle in a multiprocess pool serving requests from a single requests.Session object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365783/how-do-connections-recycle-in-a-multiprocess-pool-serving-requests-from-a-single/65466690#65466690)
>
> Thanks for this, although I'm not entirely sure how to adapt it for my case?

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

from requests import Session, Response
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


list_of_urls = [("www.site.com/" + "{0:04}".format(num)) for num in range(9999)] # one row difference with the solution from link above


def thread_pool_execute(iterables, method, pool_size=30) -> list:
    """Multiprocess requests, returns list of responses."""
    session = Session()
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=pool_size))
    session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=pool_size))
    worker = partial(method, session)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(pool_size) as pool:
        results = pool.map(worker, iterables)
    session.close()
    return list(results)

def simple_request(session, url) -> Response:
    return session.get(url)

response_list = thread_pool_execute(list_of_urls, simple_request)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried running it and got "NameError: name 'partial' is not defined" - is this a method I need to define?

Comment: Ty. Fixed the post. Added `from functools import partial` .